# Scala: Why is an abstract type member equal to a type parameter by =:= not equal in use?

Tags: scala, generics, types

I am starting to embrace abstract type members over type parameters - mainly because they seem to work better with type inference for me. However, I am still struggling to understand how to use them from outside of the types they are defined in. For example, I cannot understand why the following Scala program should not compile:

```
trait Thing

trait Describer {
  type X<:Thing
  def describe(x:X) = println(x)
}

object Program extends App {

  def print[T <: Thing, D <: Describer]
    (describer: D, thing:T)
    (implicit ev: D#X =:= T) 
    = describer.describe(thing) 

}
```

Intuitively, I would expect that the requirement `D#X =:= T` would guarantee that the two types are indeed equal and hence that instances of two could be used interchangeably, but I get this compilation error:

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : thing.type (with underlying type T)
 required: describer.X
    = describer.describe(thing)
```

What have I misunderstood? Is there another way to do what I want to do? Or failing that, is it safe to cast `thing` to the required type (`describer.X`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type of the parameter of `describer.describe` is actually `describer.X` and not `D#X`. Another thing you have to know is that `A =:= B` also functions as a conversion from `A` to `B` but (at least currently) not the other way around. So the following should work.

```
def print[T <: Thing]
  (describer: Describer, thing: T)
  (implicit ev: T =:= describer.X) 
  = describer.describe(thing)
```

Comment: Thank you. I would never have figured that out by myself.